# How to implement Microwave Signals in Unity?

Tags: unity, game-mechanics, raycasting

I need to implement microwave signals for object detection in Unity.

I know there are raycast sensors in Unity, but can microwave signals be simulated or can a proxy of microwave signals be created in Unity using the raycast sensors?

Comment: Assume your reader knows game development, but is not necessarily an expert in microwave physics. Walk us through what game behaviour you'd expect from a successful simulation of microwave signals, and we can tell you how to create that behaviour.

Comment: Basically, I am trying to simulate a vehicle actuation system in which the presence of vehicles is detected using microwave signals. Microwaves allows line-of-sight propagation. When they hit a vehicle, there is a change in their frequency, based on which presence of a vehicle is detected. Microwaves work in the frequency range between  300 MHz (1m) and 300 GHz (Imm).

Comment: Great, so edit your question to break down *what should happen in your game* based on this microwave idea. Remember, it's the game behaviour we need to know about; the microwaves are the inspiration that's guiding your choice of game mechanics, but we're not coding microwaves into the game. We're coding observable behaviour. So eg. if the microwave sensor is supposed to make the actuation system react when it has line of sight to an obstacle within 10 m, ask "How do I detect when there is an obstacle within 10 m in an object's line of sight?" or similar, depending on your needs.

Comment: The question implies that you already know about [`Physics.Raycast`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Physics.Raycast.html). Doesn't this do what you want it to do? In what way does the behavior of microwave signals differ from the behavior of regular raycasting? Remember that this is a website for game developers, not physicists. You are more likely to receive answers if your question explains the problem in a way which doesn't require any knowledge of microwave physics.